# Automator - applescript - (condition) if X button exist then click, if not, click Y button

Tags: applescript, automator

I am struggling with writing a script for opening up a webpage and click different buttons depending if the button itself exists.

I want it to be if X button exists, then click X button.
If Y button exits, then click Y button.

Both buttons wont exist the same time.

I tried putting in:

```
tell
  if exists, 
then click 
end if
```

but it does not work.
So far I have used the watch-me-do record function and got the following:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- Click the “X” button.
    delay 5.615004
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
    set uiScript to "click UI Element \"X\" of UI Element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window \"XXXXXXXXXXX" of application process \"Safari\""
    my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

    -- Click the “Y” button.
    delay 1.079871
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
    set uiScript to "click UI Element \"Y\" of UI Element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window \"YYYYYYYYYYYYY" of application process \"Safari\""
    my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    return input
end run

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

Any feedback and direction would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you ever so much!

Comment: Please provide the URL for each of the pages, one that contains the X button, the other containing the Y button and the name of each button.

Comment: there is only one page https://plusmein.com/index.php?page=freefollowers

Comment: What are the names on the buttons you are wanting to click?

Comment: -- Click the “REQUEST ADD FOLLOWERS” button.
 delay 10.372260
 set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
 set uiScript to "click UI Element \"REQUEST ADD FOLLOWERS\" of UI Element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window \"Get Free Instagram Followers - PLUSMEIN.COM | PREMIUM SERVICES | UNLIMITED\" of application process \"Safari\""
 my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )
 return input
end run

Comment: -- Click the “ [+ SUBMIT +]” button.
 delay 0.500654
 set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
 set uiScript to "click UI Element \" [+ SUBMIT +]\" of UI Element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window \"Get Free Instagram Followers - PLUSMEIN.COM | PREMIUM SERVICES | UNLIMITED\" of application process \"Safari\""
 my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )
 return input
end run

Comment: the above are the two buttons - x & y

Comment: **UI Scripting** is very kludgy and should be avoided when better methods are available. With that said, in **Safari** _if_ **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** is checked on the **Safari** > **Develop** menu, which is hidden by default and can be shown by checking **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar** in: **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Advanced** then the following _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ clicks that button: `tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('addcartbutton')[0].click();" in document 1`

Comment: Note that with the "REQUEST ADD FOLLOWERS" button the Instagram Username has to be filled in, otherwise the _click event_ is ignored.